# MySQL query for showing parent child in a table with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, pdo

We are building an application and client requirement is show child below each parent with a separator.

For eg: I have 2 tables as below

```
category:             category_description:

id(PK) | parent_id    id(fk) | name
-------|----------    -------|--------
    1  |    0             1  | Fruits
    2  |    1             2  | Apple
    3  |    1             3  | Orange
    4  |    0             4  | Veggies
    5  |    4             5  | Tomatoes
    6  |    4             6  | Cucumber

and so on ...
```

The result should show in a table as below

```
ID | Name
---|-----
 1 | Fruits
 2 | Fruits > Apple
 3 | Fruits > Orange
 4 | Veggies
 5 | Veggies > Tomatoes
 6 | Veggies > Cucumber

and so on...
```

Even if the client inserts randomly, the result should show as above.

I have tried to execute the following query

```
SELECT c.category_id AS category_id, c.parent_id, c.sort_order, 
GROUP_CONCAT(cd.name SEPARATOR '&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;') AS name FROM
category c LEFT JOIN category_description cd ON c.category_id = 
cd.category_id LEFT JOIN category_description cd1 ON cd1.category_id =
c.parent_id GROUP BY c.category_id, cd.name
```

But doesn't show the result as expected. Please let me know, where I am going wrong.

Hope, I could explain it better. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are aggregating here; a join query should work, assuming there is only a single level hierarchy:

```
SELECT
    c.ID,
    CONCAT(CASE WHEN c.parent_id = 0 THEN cd1.name ELSE cd2.name END,
        CASE WHEN c.parent_id <> 0 THEN CONCAT(' > ', cd1.name) ELSE '' END) AS Name
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN category_description cd1
    ON c.id = cd1.id
LEFT JOIN category_description cd2
    ON c.parent_id = cd2.id
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN c.parent_id = 0 THEN c.id ELSE c.parent_id END,
    c.parent_id;

    ID  Name
1   1   Fruits
2   2   Fruits > Apple
3   3   Fruits > Orange
4   4   Veggies
5   5   Veggies > Tomatoes
6   6   Veggies > Cucumber
```

### Demo

Comment: It's working, Thanks, you have solved my problem big time. When I edit, it does show parent child relation but it doesn't move below the desired parent

Comment: @Leo I don't know/see what other problem there is.  Maybe you can edit my demo and paste the link here.

Comment: I finally studied about Closure Tables and got my problem solved. I created a third table which stores the category id and parent id with depth. Now, I am stuck with displaying parent name based on parent id. Do you have any clue? Thanks.

Comment: You should open a new question.  No one is going to drop a new answer based on your above comment.